# Room data is not updating inside onDispose Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-room

I am trying to save the `HorizontalPager` currentPage state in the room database, so was thinking when the composable closes I will save the currentPage value to the database. I did it like this.

```kotlin
DisposableEffect(true) {
    (context as? Activity)?.window?.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)

    onDispose {
        scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            vm.updateBookProgress(vm.book.bookId, pagerState.currentPage+1)
        }
        (context as? Activity)?.window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
    }
}
```

but the data is not stored in the database, I am guessing that the composable was disposed of so the coroutine was cancelled? I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are true, the coroutine will get cancelled.
I suggest you have a globalViewModel or a progressViewModel initiated in the parent compose, pass it in your current compose and update your progress.

if you are not using ViewModel, you can pass a lambda to your compose from your parent composable and update progress in lambda.

example:

```
@Composable
fun HorizontalPager(onProgress: (bookId: Int, progress: Int) -> Unit){
    DisposableEffect(true) {
        (context as? Activity)?.window?.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)

        onDispose {
            onProgress(20, 10)
            (context as? Activity)?.window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
        }
    }

}
```